# add cookie to WebClient

Tags: c#

I want download pdf with `WebClient` but I need send cookie with request

How can add cookie to `WebClient` then download pdf

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

 webClient.DownloadFile("http://........", "C://2.pdf");
```

Comment: Either use HttpWebRequest or subclass WebClient and override `GetWebRequest` `GetWebResponse`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add cookies to your webClient.

```
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookies");
webClient.DownloadFile("http://........", "C://2.pdf");
```