# HTTP POST is giving unauthorized 401 Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, post

When calling the same method on `google chrome postman` after logging in, i'm getting the json object as shown below.
[image]

but when i try to get the same json result in codebehind (C#). I'm getting Unauthorized 401 exception.

I'm using my code like this.

```
using (var clientSideTab = new WebClient())
        {

            var valSideTab = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection { { "username", UserID }, { "Password", strPassword } };
            string UpldDataSideTab = "https://resapistage.namechanged.com/v3/secure/Login.aspx?userId=" + UserID + "&passwd=" + strPassword + " ";                                                

            SystemComponentWrapper SPPostWrapper = new SystemComponentWrapper();
            SystemComponentData request = new SystemComponentData();
            SystemComponentaddressId addressId = new SystemComponentaddressId();

            addressId.type = "AddressId";
            addressId.id = 19863;
            addressId.serial = "";

            request.addressId = addressId;
            request.compId = null;
            request.getCompParams = true;
            request.filterForAddress = false;

            SPPostWrapper.request = request;

            var postJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SPPostWrapper);
            Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            string postData = postJson.ToString();
            byte[] bdata = encoding.GetBytes(postData);


            string URI = "https://resapistage.namechanged.com/v3/api/secure/json/AddressInfo.svc/getSystemComponentsV2";
            clientSideTab.UploadValues(UpldDataSideTab, "POST", valSideTab);


            clientSideTab.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            clientSideTab.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");                
            clientSideTab.UploadString(URI,"POST", postData);
            //clientSideTab.UploadData(URI, "POST", bdata);

            String jsonresponse = "failed";


            Label1.Text = jsonresponse;

        }
```

I'm getting this error everytime. please help me.
[image: error]

Comment: Does the site require authentication? Are you authenticated when making the chrome call? With the C# call, are you sending your cookies that show you as authenticated?

Comment: How to send the cookie in webclient along with json data to fetch json response?

Comment: A google search led me to this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275042/add-cookie-to-webclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this.

```
            string cookie = strCookie[0]; // fetch your cookie after logging in
            clientSideTab.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8");
            clientSideTab.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");
            clientSideTab.m_container.SetCookies(URI, cookie);
            //clientSideTab.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
            String resultJSON = clientSideTab.UploadString(URI,"POST", jsonData);
```

this worked for me. hope this will help you.

Comment: Yup, I've already implemented this after searching a lot on google. anyways, thanks for your effort.