# Using only one Webclient instance in multiple XAML.cs files

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, webclient

I just need to know how can i use one instance of webclient indifferent pages..

code below

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
             webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;

            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ds.co/ee.php"));
```

Comment: Why did you tag it both Windows Phone 7 and 8?

Comment: public static WebClient webClient = new WebClient();  ? is it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a network layer. This layer will allow you to use the same WebClient for what ever you want.

For example:

```
public static class NetworkLayer{
    public static WebClient wc;

    public void InitializeWebClient(){
       wc = new WebClient();       
    }
    public void MakeCall(Uri uri){
      if(!wc.isBusy){
          wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,a)=>
          {  
             //Get your results
          };

          wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
       }
    }
}
```

MainPage.XAML.cs would reference your network layer

```
NetworkLayer.Initialize();
NetworkLayer.MakeCall(new Uri("http://www.google.com",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: thank you, how can i add cookies to webclient? i need to start session with php but i am unable to do that. this has some info but i dont understand, it doesnt work webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookies"); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275042/add-cookie-to-webclient

Comment: i have put this to my app.cs and i can reach from everywhere now         public static WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 by the way